# Order of a list resulting from a group by of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question regarding [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply)

Consider

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list)
```

Is there some guarantee on the order? For example the following suggests it does:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], "col2": [1,2,3,4,5]})

In [3]: df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list)
Out[3]:
col1
a       [1, 2]
b    [3, 4, 5]
Name: col2, dtype: object

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], "col2": [2,1,3,4,5]})

In [5]: df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list)
Out[5]:
col1
a       [2, 1]
b    [3, 4, 5]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

But is it always the case?

## Edit

In both [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.Series.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) it is mentioned that the order inside each group is preserved. However, in the example above the type of `df.groupby('col1')['col2']` is `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy` and I am not sure anymoe that the same applies also in this case. I need to know (i.e. reference to code/documentation) that the order inside each group is preserved when applying `list`.

Comment: are you specifically asking about the sort order that is returned from `apply(list)`? Because `groupby` *does* sort the groupby results. To illustrate, swap the first `a` with a `b`.

Comment: I mean *within* the group.

Comment: have either I or Wen diagnosed the problem and the expected output correctly? If not, please edit your question to better explain your question

Answer (score 0):

That is why we have `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values(['col1','col2']).groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list)
Out[79]: 
col1
a       [1, 2]
b    [3, 4, 5]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: What do you mean? Will the result adhere to the order of the `df`?

Comment: @Dror you are doing list agg , which mean the original order from your df is matter , that is why pandas will not auto sort it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be the case for *within* the groups. You can think of `apply` as sort of a glorified for loop. `apply` applies a function row-by-row. I was actually surprised when Jeff Reback himself loosely talked about this when he discussed something similar in his talk on [The future of Pandas](https://youtu.be/_-gJtO0XR48?t=7m39s).

You can validate this by looking at what happens when you look at the following `lambda` expression below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], "col2": ['a','s','d','f','g']})
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x))

col1
a      a-s
b    d-f-g
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

As for a further scope, just in case you are also asking about the sort order of the groups themselves, you can use `reset_index()` along with `sort_values()` to maniuplate the output:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x)).\
      reset_index().sort_values('col1', ascending=False)

  col1   col2
1    b  d-f-g
0    a    a-s
```